# How to call 1st html element on page load in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I am working on an HTML code as shown below in which I want to call 1st html element on page load in javascript

```
<ul class="listy-pl">
  <li class ="listy-item" data-mediaid="id_0001" tabindex="0">  //Line A
  Good Morning                                                  // Line B  
  </li>                                                         // Lina C 
  <li class ="listy-item" data-mediaid="id_0002" tabindex="0">
  Good Evening
  </li>
  <li class ="listy-item" data-mediaid="id_0003" tabindex="0">
   Hello World
  </li>
  <li class ="listy-item" data-mediaid="id_0004" tabindex="0">
  Bye
  </li>
</ul>
```

The following js script calls the Good Morning text at Line B

```
document.getElementsByClassName("listy-item")[0];
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering I should I make in javascript code above so that it renders Good Morning text on page load.

Comment: What do you mean by "calling" lines of code? You can use CSS to show/hide whatever you need.

Comment: @j08691 Is there any way we can do through script ? I just want to print Good Morning text on page load.

Comment: I know how can we do in css. It will be done through `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByClassName("listy-item")[0].style.display = "block";
document.getElementsByClassName("listy-item")[1].style.display = "none";
document.getElementsByClassName("listy-item")[2].style.display = "none";
document.getElementsByClassName("listy-item")[3].style.display = "none";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `querySelectorAll().forEach` to iterate the `li` elements and set their visibility depending on their sequence number:

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".listy-item").forEach((li, i) => 
    li.style.display = i == 0 ? "" : "none"
);
```

```html
<ul class="listy-pl">
  <li class ="listy-item" data-mediaid="id_0001" tabindex="0">
  Good Morning
  </li>
  <li class ="listy-item" data-mediaid="id_0002" tabindex="0">
  Good Evening
  </li>
  <li class ="listy-item" data-mediaid="id_0003" tabindex="0">
   Hello World
  </li>
  <li class ="listy-item" data-mediaid="id_0004" tabindex="0">
  Bye
  </li>
</ul>
```